# Contact potential between metals

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Metals Al and Au are connected in series. An ideal voltmeter, with both of its leads made of Cu, is connected across them. Then how come the voltmeter gives zero reading but why can't we measure contact potential between them if there is potential difference electrons flow right then why electron flow can't be measured
If so how can we prove on paper that it is 0 V

Comment: There are three junctions in your circuit: Au/Al, Al/Cu, Cu/Au.

Comment: I am interested in only between Al and Au you can consider only between them

Comment: That is fine for you to only consider one junction, but the voltmeter sees all three. It must see 0 volts, or you could connect Cu to Cu (no voltage) and have net voltage around a closed loop.

Comment: Ok consider all but how it is 0 it should measure contact potential right

Comment: The Cu/Al, Al/Au and Au/Cu contact potentials add up to 0.